# How to launch App when received firebase push notification without clicking on the notification Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I tried to open the app when received the firebase push notification without clicking on the notification. it is worked from the receiver if Android version is below 10 but not 10 and above is there any solution to launch app in 10 and above versions.

I tried using broadcast receiver it is worked for the below android version 10 but not 10 and above.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions on Stack Overflow.  The last time you asked this, you got an explanation that what you're trying to do isn't possible in newer versions of Android.  This is explained in the duplicate question and the link to documentation you were provided last time.  These facts aren't going to change.  If you feel that you have a different problem than the one being described in the duplicate, you should take some time to explain in more detail why your problem is different.

Answer (score 0):

Request "draw over other apps" permission. If you receive a broadcast, start a service, and the service will launch your app.